# Deploying an Angular website to github pages

Tags: node.js, angular, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my personal website to [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/), it is a very simple one page website developed in Angular2 (using Angular CLI) with some information about me.

The process seemed simple, create a repository called `christopherkade.github.io` and push my code to it, after doing so my Angular CLI `README` is being displayed at my [website](https://christopherkade.github.io/).

A couple of questions:

- Do I required a `NodeJS` server (that I have been using in parallel to my Angular2 app) to run my app on `Github pages`? (I do not need a backend, I guess that may answer my question)
- How may I deploy my website using `Githb pages`? The documentation lets me deploy a single `http` file and I cannot figure out how to deploy a fully fledged website.

Here is my [repository](https://github.com/christopherkade/christopherkade.github.io).

Comment: You don't require NodeJS server. Set `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true}]` and commit the build output according to the GitHub pages docs.

Comment: I don't have any routes, I use `ng2-page-scroll` in order to do a one page website.

Comment: Gunter is right. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages for referenece.

Comment: Understood, what if I do not use any routes, should I still set the import?

Comment: Incase if you don't have any routes, I guess you can skip the part of imports. You can give it a try and reply back if theres any problem.

Comment: I have, and the result is the same. I did not add any new import though.

Comment: What exactly is the current result?

Comment: You can also you travis ci to build and deploy to gh pages https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I followed the deployment via angular-cli-ghpages and receive a 404 error on my website.

Comment: But you didn't get any error for the angular-cli-ghpages command? You can investigate the GitHub repositories ghpages branch to see what's there. Perhaps you're just using the wrong URL to access the Angular application

Comment: I did not get any errors, I get a `Successfully published!` after doing `angular-cli-ghpages`. I access it with `christopherkade.github.io` and built it with `ng build --prod --base-href "https://christopherkade.github.io/christopherkade.github.io/"`

Comment: Try `ngh --branch=master` or just commit the content of the checked out directory

Comment: Okay I made it work following this tutorial: http://shermandigital.com/blog/deploy-an-angular-cli-application-to-github-pages/
I basically had to do a different command to build my project & deploy it.
We answered at the same time, but your answer is exactly what made it work, can you create an answer so I can accept it? Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Nice website Chris, is that ng4 ?

Comment: Thank you @dparkar ! Yes i'm working with Angular 4

Comment: There is a nice e quite quick tutorial on Youtube in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKXkC4SqtRk on how to deploy to GHPages.